# Git open default git editor instead of VIM or any other editor (Git Rebase)

Tags: git, vim, git-interactive-rebase

I recently installed Vim. Now, when I rebase my branch in interactive mode, Git automatically opens Vim.

However, I do not want to open Vim in interactive mode; instead, I want to open default Git interactive mode editor. How can I set the default interactive editor used by Git?

Comment: What do you mean by "default Git interactive mode editor"?

Comment: yes default editor how can I set.

Comment: that question explain how to set editor but my question is how to set default editor, also which one is git default editor. So i think not a duplicate. Let me inform if this duplicate then I delete?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "default editor". It likely depends on which OS you're using.

Comment: Actually I am use ubuntu, and I don't know which one is default git editor in ubuntu.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think what you want is to use nano (which is the default text editor on Ubuntu), you can set that up by:

```
git config --global core.editor "nano"
```

or

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

Comment: "nano" is default editor, now i know thanks a lot.

Comment: I want to get back to Vim, so thanks also